# Node Sequelize find where $like wildcard

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to add a where like clause to a Node Sequelize findAll, to behave like the sql query `select * from myData where name like '%Bob%'` with the below code

```
let data: Array<any> = await MyDataSequelizeAccess.findAll({
  where: {
    name: {
      $like: `%Bob%`
    }
  }
});
```

Which is returning the below error

> Invalid value { '$like': '%Bob%' }

How can I perform that type of where wildcard or where like on my sequelize object?

```
let data: Array<any> = await MyDataSequelizeAccess.findAll({
  where: {
    name: `Bob`
  }
});
```

This works as expected, but I cannot get the wildcard to work.

*updated* still no dice - per https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/querying/#operators my syntax looks correct

I'm also trying (and failing) to do the same with $not as in

```
let data: Array<any> = await MyDataSequelizeAccess.findAll({
  where: {
    name: {
      $not: `Bob`
    }
  }
});
```

and getting the same error as above `Invalid value { '$not': '%Bob%' }`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

String operators (e.g. `$operator`) is legacy in V5 of Sequelize <sup>[[1]](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md)</sup>.
You can still execute queries with operators the legacy way, but the connection has to be setup with aliases for operators (there will be a deprecation warning about this). <sup>[[2]](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/c6d733383dd9b877988784f28f23d47e256125f8/docs/querying.md#operators-aliases)</sup>

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const operatorsAliases = {
  $like: Op.like,
  $not: Op.not
}
const connection = new Sequelize(db, user, pass, { operatorsAliases })

[Op.like]:  '%Bob%' // LIKE '%Bob%'
$like: '%Bob%' // same as using Op.like (LIKE '%Bob%')
```

The updated documentation for `Sequelize.js` provides operators in the `Sequelize.Op` module as Symbol operators. <sup>[[3]](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators)</sup>

Sequelize uses Symbol operators by default to minimize the risk of operators injected in the query; it's advised to use Symbol operators going forward. <sup>[[4]](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/c6d733383dd9b877988784f28f23d47e256125f8/docs/querying.md#operators-security)</sup>

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

let data: Array<any> = await MyDataSequelizeAccess.findAll({
  where: {
    name: {
      [Op.like]: '%Bob%'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: How to make this same query with lower function in field name?

Comment: To use variable instead of '%Bob%' 
name: {
                        [Op.like]: `%${name}%`
                    }

Answer (score 6):

Express sequelize
first import express and defile  Op like so:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const { search } = await req.body;
```

The do like so:

```
const users = await User.findAll({
    where: {
      username: { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` },
    },
    include: [{ model: Tweet, as: "Tweets" }],
    raw: true,
  }).catch(errorHandler);
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use operator [Op.substring] instead of [Op.like], so we don't have to append "%" symbols.

```
await Model.findAll({
    where: {
        name: { [Op.substring]: "bob" }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is looking for example use with express.js

### GET request body

```
 {
    "searchString": "search",
    "count": 0,
    "limit": 20
}
```

### express.js with sequelize

```
app.get("/api/saloon", function (req, res) {
Saloon.findAll({
    where: {
        name: {[Op.iLike]: `%${req.body.searchString}%`}
    },
    offset: req.body.count,
    limit: req.body.limit,
})
```