# Dynamic where clauses Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, where-clause

I have the following code:

```
const { TN, TITLE, QUEUE, TYPE, SERVICE, OWNER, CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_USER_ID, CREATE_BY, create_time, ESTADO_DO_SLA } = req.query;

    let query = {};
    if (TN != null) query.TN = TN;
    if (TITLE != null) query.TITLE = TITLE;
    if (QUEUE != null) query.QUEUE = QUEUE;
    if (TYPE != null) query.TYPE = TYPE;
    if (SERVICE != null) query.SERVICE = SERVICE;
    if (OWNER != null) query.OWNER = OWNER;
    if (CUSTOMER_ID != null) query.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_ID;
    if (CUSTOMER_USER_ID != null) query.CUSTOMER_USER_ID = CUSTOMER_USER_ID;
    if (CREATE_BY != null) query.CREATE_BY = CREATE_BY;

    const limit = req.query.limit != null ? Number.parseInt(req.query.limit) : 1000;
    const page = req.query.page != null ? (Number.parseInt(req.query.page) * limit) - limit : 0;


    const tickets = await ViewSLA.findAll({
        raw: true,
        offset: page,
        limit: limit,
        where: query
    });
```

The point is, the **where** part is working, but only matches if the value is equal, but I would like to do some *Op.like* in certains parameters and keep others optional.

For example, make sense to match the exact value of the TN (Ticket Number) parameter, but I would like to filter by the TITLE param, if it was informed, using a *like* in where clause.

Is that possible?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972540/294949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way:

```
const { TN, TITLE, QUEUE, TYPE, SERVICE, OWNER, CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_USER_ID, CREATE_BY, create_time, ESTADO_DO_SLA } = req.query;

        let query = {};
        if (TN != null) query.TN = TN;
        if (TITLE != null) query.TITLE = {
            [Op.like]: `%${TITLE}%`
        };
        if (QUEUE != null) query.QUEUE = QUEUE;
        if (TYPE != null) query.TYPE = TYPE;
        if (SERVICE != null) query.SERVICE = SERVICE;
        if (OWNER != null) query.OWNER = OWNER;
        if (CUSTOMER_ID != null) query.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_ID;
        if (CUSTOMER_USER_ID != null) query.CUSTOMER_USER_ID = CUSTOMER_USER_ID;
        if (CREATE_BY != null) query.CREATE_BY = CREATE_BY;
        if (ESTADO_DO_SLA != null) query.ESTADO_DO_SLA = ESTADO_DO_SLA;

        const limit = req.query.limit != null ? Number.parseInt(req.query.limit) : countTickets;
        const page = req.query.page != null ? (Number.parseInt(req.query.page) * limit) - limit : 0;


        const tickets = await ViewSLA.findAll({
            raw: true,
            offset: page,
            limit: limit,
            where: query
        });
```

Worked like a charm.